# CString replacing multiple Whitespace MFC

Tags: c++, cstring

I have CStrings with single/multiple whitespaces in my MFC application. I have to replace them with single underscore.
Example: sampleString=

```
"A B  C D   E" --> "A_B_C_D_E"
```

But when I use sampleString.Replace(" ",'_'), underscore appears for each spaces i.e.

```
"A_B__C_D___E".
```

I have written a code but didnot like it much ,also it is faulty.

```
                int i=0,pos=0,lastSpacePos=sampleString.GetLength();
                while(i<sampleString.GetLength())
                {
                    pos=sampleString.Find(" ",i);
                    if(pos!=-1)
                    {
                        if(lastSpacePos!=(pos-1))
                        {
                            sampleString.Delete(pos,1);
                            sampleString.Insert(pos,"_");
                        }                        
                        lastSpacePos=pos;
                        i=pos+1;
                    }
                    else
                        i++;
                }
                sampleString.Remove(' ');
```

Is there any simpler method that I am missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300582%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) returns the number of characters to replace found so you can try replacing two spaces with one space until no more space pairs are found:

```
while(sampleString.Replace("  "," "));
```

And then replace one space with underscore:

```
sampleString.Replace(" ",'_');
```

Comment: @Codename_DJ You are welcome! remember that if you liked the answer you can accept it by clicking the mark below it.

Comment: Yeah :P .. I have already tried making it the correct answer. But a popup came up saying I can select answer after 2 mintues .